# Reading all subsequent lines after a certain line in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python code which is supposed to find the word "ACT" in a file. Once it finds "ACT" it should write all the lines that follow onto the output file. My code writes everything from the input file into the output file. What am I doing wrong?

```
    found_ACT = False
    for line in inputFile:
        line.strip()
        if found_ACT:
            outputFile.write(line)
        else:
            if "ACT" in line:
                found_ACT = True
```

Comment: This is not a [MCVE] (for one, the indentation is all wrong, and for another, I'm pretty sure it would work correctly). Make sure it is actually verifiable (someone can run it with a given input and reproduce your incorrect output).

Comment: This recent answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525317/how-to-strip-the-beginning-of-a-file-with-python-library-re-sub

Comment: Can you post your text?

Comment: Thanks. It actually works but there was another "ACT" string hiding in the file that preceded the one I was targetting

Answer (score 0):

You never change `found_ACT` to `False` if it is not found in `line`. You should put `found_ACT = False` inside the loop, or just use `"ACT" in line` directly.

```
for line in inputFile:
    line.strip()
    if "ACT" in line:
        outputFile.write(line)
```

Comment: I can see why you're suggesting to put the Boolean tester inside the loop but its working fine now. Thanks!